# At-Sign in SQL statement before column name

Tags: mysql, sql, symbols, at-command

I have an INSERT statement in a PHP-file wherein at-signs (@) are occurring in front of the column name.

@field1,
   @field2,

It is a MySQL database. What does the at-sign mean?

**Edit:**
There is no  `SET @field1 := 'test'` in the PHP script. The PHP script reads a csv and puts the data into the table. Can it be misused as a commenting out feature?

```
<?php
$typo_db_username = 'xyz';  //  Modified or inserted by TYPO3 Install Tool.
$typo_db_password = 'xyz';  //  Modified or inserted by TYPO3 Install Tool.

// login
$_SESSION['host'] = "localhost";
$_SESSION['port'] = "3306";
$_SESSION['user'] = $typo_db_username;
$_SESSION['password'] = $typo_db_password;
$_SESSION['dbname'] = "database";


$cxn = mysqli_connect($_SESSION['host'], $_SESSION['user'], $_SESSION['password'], $_SESSION['dbname'], $_SESSION['port']) or die ("SQL Error:" . mysqli_connect_error() );
mysqli_query($cxn, "SET NAMES utf8");

$sqltrunc = "TRUNCATE TABLE tablename";
$resulttrunc = mysqli_query($cxn,$sqltrunc) or die ("Couldn’t execute query: ".mysqli_error($cxn));

$sql1 = "
LOAD DATA LOCAL
INFILE 'import.csv'
REPLACE
INTO TABLE tablename
FIELDS
TERMINATED BY ';'
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"'
IGNORE 1 LINES
(
`normalField`,
@field1,
@field2,
`normalField2`,
@field3,
@field4
)";

$result1 = mysqli_query($cxn,$sql1) or die ("Couldn’t execute query: " . mysqli_error($cxn));


?>'
```

**SOLUTION**:

Finally, I found it out! The @ field is used as dummy to miss out a column in a csv-file. See http://www.php-resource.de/forum/showthread/t-97082.html
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/load-data.html

Comment: @testing - I see you've added a "Possible duplicate" into your own question so chucked in a close vote on that basis. Can you clarify does that answer your question though?

Comment: It's not a dupe, the links asks the difference between a normal var and a `@var`, this question asks what `@xyz` in a query means.

Comment: It would be easier to get specific if you include the **relevant** php-code with the query in it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL: @variable vs. variable. Whats the difference?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009954/mysql-variable-vs-variable-whats-the-difference)

Answer (score 12):

The `@` sign is a variable in SQL.

In MySQL it is used to store a value between consecutive runs of a query, or to transfer data between two different queries.

An example

**Transfer data between two queries**

```
SELECT @biggest:= MAX(field1) FROM atable;
SELECT * FROM bigger_table WHERE field1 > @biggest;
```

Another usage is in ranking, which MySQL doesn't have native support for.

**Store a value for consecutive runs of a query**

```
INSERT INTO table2
  SELECT @rank := @rank + 1, table1.* FROM table1
  JOIN( SELECT @rank := 0 ) AS init
  ORDER BY number_of_users DESC
```

Note that in order for this to work, the order in which the rows get processed in the query must be fixed, it's easy to get this wrong.

See:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-variables.html
[mysql sorting and ranking statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7056895/mysql-sorting-and-ranking-statment)
http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/15/advanced-mysql-user-variable-techniques/

**UPDATE**
This code will never work.
You've just opened the connection before and nowhere are the @fields set.
So currently they hold `null` values.
To top that, **you cannot use @vars to denote fieldnames**, you can **only** use @vars for values.

```
$sql1 = "
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'import.csv'
REPLACE INTO TABLE tablename
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"'
IGNORE 1 LINES
(`normalField`, @field1, @field2, `normalField2`, @field3, @field4)";
```

Comment: Can the value be stored in another php script? Can it be used over the borders of a php file? Because the values are never set in the script I have ...

Comment: No, `@vars` are connection specific. You cannot transfer them between connections.

Comment: The script is not from me. I have to correct it ... You mean that null values are imported. Which consequence does this have? The best solution would be to replace or remove that fields?

Comment: I mean the code will never work, because it is a syntax and a logical error. I would replace the `@field` with the literal names of the fields. If you insist on using dynamic field names, read this question first: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5811834/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-with-dynamic-tablenames and make sure you whitelist those fieldnames **before** you inject them.