# variables in SQL for monetdb

Tags: mysql, sql, variables, select, monetdb

I am confused whether at-sign variables could ever work in MonetDB. Is it standard SQL or only mySQL? (See e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7230099/938408) answer here on SO.) MonetDB claims to support SQL:2003 (full feature list [here](https://www.monetdb.org/book/export/html/314), hard for me to parse), but [this](https://www.monetdb.org/Documentation/Manuals/SQLreference/Variables) is what they say on variables.

The following line fails in MonetDB complaining about the unexpected symbol `:`. But is there a way to get this work? I see no way to combine a `SET` (after `DECLARE`) with `SELECT`.

```
SELECT @firstq := QUANTILE(share26_2007,0.25) FROM sys.share26_2007;
```

(Afterwards, the following is the intended use case:)

```
SELECT peorglopnr, CASE WHEN share26_2007 < @firstq THEN 1
```

Comment: There are no variables in standard SQL. The SQL standard defines variables only for procedural languages (SQL/PSM).

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thanks — then do you understand how/whether I can use `SET` with a `SELECT`? The monetdb example is about setting a declared variable with a value "manually," not with the result of a query…

Comment: I have no experience with MonetDB. But if the manual says so, I would believe the manual.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Any experience with `SET` would help, the documentation does not rule any of this out, just uses a simpler example. But of course, thanks already!

Answer (score -1):

As already pointed out in the comments, `@` variables are not standard SQL.

Using `DECLARE` and `SET` would work::

```
DECLARE firstq double;
SET firstq = ( SELECT quantile(share26_2007, 0.25) FROM share26_2007 );

SELECT peorglopnr, CASE WHEN share26_2007 < firstq THEN 1 .....
```

Notes:

- What I understand from your example is that you have a table `share26_2007` which has a column `share26_2007`. I followed this assumption.
- I declared the variable `firstq` as `double`. Your example does not specify the type of column `share26_2007`. Change the variable type accordingly.
- When setting the value of a variable to the result of a SELECT that returns an atomic value, you do need parentheses around the SELECT.
- At this moment `quantile` seems not to work correctly in MonetDB (see https://www.monetdb.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=4076), but this is unrelated to your question. The syntax above works (you may want to verify that by replacing `quantile` with `sys.quantile`)