# SQL SELECT query not working with Email Addresses

Tags: mysql, sql, select, email-validation

I am trying to query an e-mail address stored in my database for log-in. I am having issues with the query in PHP, when I attempted the query with SQL in PHPMyAdmin it returns an empty set. After doing some testing I determined the following for an email of something@gmail.com:

Works:

```
SELECT * FROM `Careers` WHERE `Email` LIKE '%something%' and

SELECT * FROM `Careers` WHERE `Email` LIKE '%gmail.com%' and

SELECT * FROM `Careers` WHERE `Email` LIKE '%@%'.
```

Doesn't work:

```
SELECT * FROM `Careers` WHERE `Email` LIKE 'something@gmail.com' and

SELECT * FROM `Careers` WHERE `Email` LIKE '%something@gmail.com%' and

SELECT * FROM `Careers` WHERE `Email` LIKE '%@gmail.com%'

SELECT * FROM `Careers` WHERE `Email` LIKE '%something%gmail.com'
```

I'm completely lost as to how to correct this. The only think I can think of is it is an issue with the @ sign as when I add the @ sign the query seems to fail. Any help you could provide would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you confirm the last line of 'Works' and of 'Doesn't work' ? Because the last line of Works contains an '@' when the last line of Doesn't Work does not contain it.

Comment: @LaurentCrivello Yes, I have executed each of these queries on my database. I'm not sure why the last 'Doesn't Work' fails and the last line of 'works' does.

Comment: @Nmaduro i am not able to recreate your issue [link]http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e9e21/3

Comment: have you tried escaping the @ sign e.g. \@ I'm more familiar with Oracle or SQLServer syntax so not 100% sure

Comment: Perhaps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7230068/at-sign-in-sql-statement-before-column-name  in oracle set define off will turn off the user defined nature of this.  Perhaps MySQL has a default setting which was changed to no longer ignore @ as user variables.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you sure that it's not working. See a proof here that it works  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/26b00/4. But you should change your queries a bit as shown below

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE `Email` = 'something@gmail.com' -- No need of LIKE operator

SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE `Email` = 'something@gmail.com' -- No need of LIKE operator

SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE `Email` LIKE '%@gmail.com' -- search before string

SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE `Email` LIKE 'something_gmail.com' -- search a single char
```

**EDIT:**

Per your latest comment your collation `armscii8_general_ci` is the issue here. For example create the table like

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    (`email` varchar(19) collate armscii8_general_ci)
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    (`email`)
VALUES
    ('something@gmail.com')
;
```

Do a `select * ...` returns below; as you can see the `.` as turned to `©` kind of copyright symbol and that's why the wildcard with `LIKE` operator not working.

```
something@gmail©com
```

Change your query to use `_` wilcard with `LIKE` operator to match any single character and it will work fine. See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ec46f/8

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE `Email` LIKE 'something@gmail_com';
```

Comment: @Sachu, Yes and even I have made the same statement with a fiddle in answer but when searching for entire string literal there is no need of LIKE operator and that's what a, trying to point here.

Comment: oh ok..sorry for not checking the fiddle :)

Comment: @Sachu maybe it is something with how the database is collated? I'm using armscii8_general_ci. Fiddle doesn't state what collation is used. Any idea?

Comment: @NMaduro, Yes that's the issue here; see edit in answer if that helps.

Comment: @Sachu What would you recommend as the collation I use? Thank you so much, by the way! This has been driving me crazy for weeks! Lol

Comment: @NMaduro above answer solved the issue?in your question u said `SELECT * FROM Careers WHERE Email LIKE '%gmail.com%' and` is working if this is the case it wont select any data

Comment: Sorry @Sachu just now had the time to get home and test before selecting your answer as the correct one. Thanks for helping me out with this. I ended up using UTF8_general_ci as the collation.

Comment: @NMaduro, from yesterday you are bit confused, it's not Sachu; Sachu made his comment in my answer ... LOL ... funny :)

Answer (score 1):

Use the Regex force! Just a where statement to solve this:

```
select * from site_form
where email REGEXP '^[A-Za-z0-9._%\-+!#$&/=?^|~]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+[.][A-Za-z]+$';
```